# ffmpeg: Extract unknown data stream from video container

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a .MOV container which contains the following tracks:

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 100619 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2020-07-21T22:48:24.000000Z
  handler_name    : DJI.AVC
  encoder         : AVC encoder
Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (priv / 0x76697270), 87 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2020-07-21T22:48:24.000000Z
  handler_name    : DJI.Meta
Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574), 2 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2020-07-21T22:48:24.000000Z
  handler_name    : DJI.Subtitle
```

As you can see, stream #0:1, called DJI.meta, is of an unknown data format. I just want to extract the raw data of this stream to a file. So that is the ffmpeg command I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i .\DJI_0001.MOV -map 0:1 metadata
```

But using this command results in the following error:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'metadata'
metadata: Invalid argument
```

How can I tell ffmpeg that the data should not be formated, so that only the raw data is extracted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0:d -c copy -copy_unknown -f data raw.bin
```

Comment: The command does the following things: map only the data stream, set codec to copy so there's no transformation, set copy_unknown since there's no recognized decoder and ffmpeg may fail a copy on that account. Set the data muxer so no other data is added to the copied stream packets.